# Which are the ways to redirect the execution flow, from user-space to kernel in x86_64?

Tags: kernel, x86-64, userspace

I know two ways to redirect the execution flow, from user-space to kernel in x86_64:

**1. SYSCALL Service**

**2. Software interrupts**

Is there any other way to go into kernel from user-space?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By kernel do you mean Ring 0? Off the top of my head: `call` (but not `jmp`), `sysenter` and exceptions (e.g. page faults, debug exceptions and similar).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: yeah, AFAIK that's all.  I made a list of user->kernel methods that can be used as a system-call ABI on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022184/osdev-syscall-sysret-and-sysenter-sysexit-instructions-enabling).  Apparently an invalid-instruction trap was the fastest way on 80386, and actually used for system calls by Windows/386.  Can you use `iret` from user-space for this?  I know you can use `iret` as an alternative to `far jmp`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Nice answer there. `iret` can only transfer control to less or equal privileged code.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Yes I mean Ring 0. How can I got to Ring 0 from Ring 3 with a call? Interesting, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @PeterCordes very interesting link, nice apport, thanks.

Comment: Do you know how exceptions are handled? Is there a way to register a handler or how does it work?

Comment: @MargaretBloom if you refered to `call gates` when said `call` I found it in the Peter's link. https://wiki.osdev.org/System_Calls#Call_Gates_.28Intel.29

Comment: I guess we can include Exceptions in the group of system interrupts that pertain to IDT way: https://wiki.osdev.org/Exceptions